# Call to a member function send() on string

Tags: laravel, sendmail, member-functions

I got the call to a member function send() on string. I tried to read other questions w ith this title but none of them seems to be my case.

This is how my function looks like:

```php
public function sendProjectTeam($clientId) {
   $clientEmail = Client::where('id', $clientId)->value('email');
   Mail::to($clientEmail->send(new ProjectRequestMail()));
   return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I got the error **Call to a member function send() on string** when I use `send() `inside the above function.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the send method on the `$clientEmail` string instead of the `Illuminate\Mail\PendingMail` instance.

It should be:

```
Mail::to($clientEmail)->send(new ProjectRequestMail);
// ------------------^ The closing parenthesis
```